I'm trying to use SPI and LoRa and when I initialize the SPI (with custom pins) I get a crash
I am using an ESP32-WROOM-32E with 2 MB PSRAM. If I comment out the begin of the vspi, the code will not crash. (Any help would really be appreciated!)
vspi = new SPIClass(VSPI);
vspi->setHwCs(false);
DebugPrintln("FREE HEAP: %d", ESP.getFreeHeap()); //  (192.3K)
vspi->begin(MY_SPI_SCK, MY_SPI_MISO, MY_SPI_MOSI,MY_SPI_NSS);
DebugPrintln("FREE HEAP: %d", ESP.getFreeHeap()); //  (192.0K)
LoRa.setSPI(*vspi);
LoRa.setPins(MY_SPI_NSS, MY_LORA_RESET, MY_LORA_DIO0);
DebugPrintln("SPI initialized.");

if (!LoRa.begin(915E6)) {
  DebugPrintln("Starting Long Range failed!");
} else {
  DebugPrintln("Long range initialized!");
}

My SPI pins are as follows:
const int MY_SPI_MOSI = 16; 
const int MY_SPI_MISO = 23; 
const int MY_SPI_SCK  = 14; 
const int MY_SPI_NSS  = 5; 
const int MY_LORA_RESET = 2; 
const int MY_LORA_DIO0  = 26; 

The crash I see is with the hw  serial (I am outputting a "." in loop() once a second). loopheap is 78K.
Here is the stack trace on crash:
0x40098cf9: xQueueSemaphoreTake at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/freertos/queue.c line 1545
0x4010288d: uart_tx_all at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/driver/uart.c line 1231
0x40103189: uart_write_bytes at /home/runner/work/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp32-arduino-lib-builder/esp-idf/components/driver/uart.c line 1284
0x400ffdf9: uartWriteBuf at C:/Users/danie/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-uart.c line 686
0x400fc8f1: HardwareSerial::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) at C:/Users/danie/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/HardwareSerial.cpp line 472
0x400fce87: Print::write(char const*) at C:/Users/danie/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Print.h line 67
0x400fcf41: Print::print(char const*) at C:/Users/danie/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Print.cpp line 84
0x400da989: loop() at src/main.cpp line 4139
0x401004f5: loopTask(void*) at C:/Users/danie/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/main.cpp line 50

Line 4139 is Serial.print(".");.
I tried to use custom pins to initialize SPI before using LoRa. I expected the code to run like before I called begin on SPI.

The line of the crash is not in your example, also you put some unrelated info, like pin configurations, it's unlikely the root cause of the crash.

Lora.begin() internally would call _spi->begin() so the line vspi->begin(MY_SPI_SCK, MY_SPI_MISO, MY_SPI_MOSI,MY_SPI_NSS); is not necessary and the _spi->begin() been called twice in your code. BTW, you don't write more than 4139 lines of code to know that the configuration of an SPI is not working. Test it frequency and test each function when writing code.

Found it. Two issues. One, I used IO16.  It is also used by psram.   And two,  I was running out of heap.

Found it. Two issues. One, I used IO16. It is also used by psram. And two, I was running out of heap.
